# Eclipse console not displaying output

Tags: eclipse

So this should be displaying 2^70000 but instead the console shows a blank screen. I tried going to the console settings and turning off "limit console output" but it still shows a blank screen. Is this number just show large the console can't display it in one line? and if so is there a way I could split it onto multiple lines so I could view it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BigInteger num = new BigInteger ("2");
    int exponent = 70000;
    BigInteger answer = new BigInteger ("1");
    answer = num.pow(exponent);
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although a BigInteger is *theoretically* limitless, there are practical limits set by your OS and JVM, and I am going to guess that you are hitting them.  2^70000 is approximately 10^21000. This is an absurdly large number.

(My copy of Excel overflows at 2^2000. My copy of Windows Calculator overflows as well.)

Comment: Is there anyway around that or some other program that could be used? I was trying to see if I could print out 2^74,207,281 − 1, which is the largest prime number found so far

Comment: And so was the problem that it couldn't actually finish the computation or that it just couldn't display it?

Comment: It's almost certainly a problem of computation. Suggestion: Try a loop and on each iteration print 2^N; that way you can find out exactly when your local environment craps out.

Comment: It looks like it can't handle anything past 2^15546. So is there anyway I could get more processing power? Or is the only option getting a more powerful computer

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate it because BigInteger uses int[] array in it's implementation. Each position in array contains one number and array maximuim size is `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5`. After that point you should get:

```
  Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

Perhaps this exception is handled by BigInteger and that is why you are getting blank space as the result.